# Qt Creator 4.2 - CMake

Tags: ros, roscpp, qtcreator, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Today,

I updated Qt Creator from some 3.x version to 4.2 and now it can't run CMake as before :s
I tried both sugestion without success, set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and "roscpp_DIR"

```
Running "/usr/bin/cmake /home/ze/catkin/src/WiiGo_sw/wiigo_safe '-GCodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=/home/ze/Qt/5.5/gcc_64 -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=/home/ze/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/bin/qmake -Droscpp_DIR:PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp/cmake/roscppConfig.cmake" in /tmp/qtc-cmake-X0aSlj.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /tmp/qtc-cmake-X0aSlj/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/ze/Qt/5.5/gcc_64
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /tmp/qtc-cmake-X0aSlj/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" with any
  of the following names:

    roscppConfig.cmake
    roscpp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "roscpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "roscpp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "roscpp"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'roscpp'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/qtc-cmake-X0aSlj/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/qtc-cmake-X0aSlj/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" with any
  of the following names:

    roscppConfig.cmake
    roscpp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "roscpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "roscpp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "roscpp"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


*** cmake process exited with exit code 1.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251262/qt-creator-4.2---cmake/) by [metRo_](https://answers.ros.org/users/23114/metro_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=/home/ze/Qt/5.5/gcc_64 need to change it to -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=home/ze/catkin/devel;/opt/ros/indigo

Why this happen I don;t know...

---

Originally posted by [metRo_](https://answers.ros.org/users/23114/metro_/) with karma: 58 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2